# Wordpress get date registered in custom field but be able to edit it?

Tags: php, wordpress, field

I am trying to add a custom field to the backend of wordpress in user profiles. I want it to get the date registered, but then have it so you can edit the field and overwrite it?

Ive currently got it to pull the date registered but need a way of making it so it just initially pulls the date registered value but will overwrite if modified?

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Date Registered</h3>
<?php $userr_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="date_reg"><?php _e("Date Registered"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="datereg" id="datereg" value="<?php echo the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $userr_ID ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
<?php }
```

Answer (score -1):

> Old broken code.

```
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields');

function update_extra_profile_fields($userID) {
     if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$userID) )
         update_user_meta($userID, 'user_registered', current_time( 'mysql' ));
}
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
    <h3>Date Registered</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="date_reg"><?php _e("Date Registered"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="datereg" id="datereg" value="<?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $user->ID); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields', 10, 1 );
```

> Updated working code.

```
add_action('profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields', 10, 2);
function update_extra_profile_fields($userID, $oldData) {
    if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$userID) ) {
        $updattionDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $update = update_user_meta($userID, 'user_registered', $updattionDate);
    }
}
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
    <h3>Date Registered</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="date_reg"><?php _e("Date Registered"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <?php 
                $registrationTime = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_registered', true);; 
                $registrationDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date($registrationTime)));
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="datereg" id="datereg" value="<?php echo $registrationDate;  ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields', 10, 1 );
```

I noticed an error in my profile updation code namely the wrong hook. The correct for user profile update event is `profile_update` and not `edit_user_profile_update`

Even with this fixed you will still not see the correct registration date as we are calling the wrong function for it. We were retrieving date using `get_the_author_meta` which retrieves the data of the author of current post. The correct function for this is `get_user_meta`. So the updated code written above is working properly.

Below are the screenshot of the same code implemented in one of my projects.

Functions File:
[image: functions.php file]

Before Profile Updated
[image: Before the profile has been updated.]

After Profile Updated
[image: After the profile has been updated.]

Comment: But how can i initially populate the field with data registered then it can be editable?

Comment: @jord49 The code that you have written in action callback for `show_user_profile` and `edit_user_profile` should get you the data you need and it will be editable. The profile update hook `edit_user_profile_update` will provide you all of your submitted data in `$_POST` variable.

Comment: @jord49 Please check the updated code and my apologies for the mix up with the hook.

Comment: Still broken man :( That code shows a place holder 1970 date when you load the page, when you clicked update it then gets the date, then doesnt save it if you change it.

Comment: @jord49 Did you change anything in the code regarding date display function or date save function? I have added0 screenshot showing the exact same code working properly.